# OSX Automator "Ask for Text" action: How to localize the text that asks for input?

Tags: macos, localization, automator

I have an Automator action that uses the OSX standard action "Ask for text". This action outputs first a question and waits then for the user's answer.
The question is typed into the action during editing in Automator, see image below.

My question is: **How do I localize the question?**

In the image (sorry for the German), the header is the name of the standard action "Ask for text", the placeholder for the first line is "Question" (here the localized question should appear), the placeholder of the 2nd line is a standard answer that I don't use, and the checkbox means that an answer is required.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now, I am convinced that it is not possible to localize the question in the "Ask for text" action.
One has to write a new action, e.g. an Obj-C action, that displays a similar user interface.
It is surprisingly easy to write such an action in Xcode, see the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/ImplementObjCAction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001513-BCICCECC). The Xcode project can then easily be localized.